# Creating generic components in React Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build a React select component that can support multiple different child component types.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
export const GenericSelect = (props) => {
  const { component, items } = props;
  return <>{items && items.map((item, index) => <component id={items.id} name={item.name} />)}</>;
};
```

And then be able to use it like:

```
<GenericSelect component={NonGenericCard} items={items} />
```

Where NonGenericCard supports a fixed set of properties (e.g., id, name), which will be populated from values in the items object.

I tried this, but it doesn't seem like it can create the `<component/>` at run-time.

**Is this possible in Javascript? If so, how can it be accomplished?**

Comment: `component` must be capitalized => `Component`. Change the name of your prop. Lowercase component names are not allowed as they get confused with the native elements like `div`, or `p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSX, lower-case tag names are considered to be HTML tags. So you should use `Component` instead of `component`.

Also id should be `item.id` instead of `items.id` and you should give each element a key.

```js
export const GenericSelect = (props) => {
  const { Component, items } = props;
  return (
    <>
      {items &&
        items.map((item, index) => (
          <Component key={item.id} id={item.id} name={item.name} />
        ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
<GenericSelect Component={NonGenericCard} items={items} />
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized